# problem with "self" operator when inheriting from a class i wrote

Tags: python, class, inheritance, self

I defined a two classes within one file. I was able to have it run after separating the classes into two files, but I wanted to know why the first attempt does not work.

The traceback read:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Polygon.py", line 15, in <module>
    class Triangle(Polygon):
  File "Polygon.py", line 21, in Triangle
    print(self.sides)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

and the bare bones of my code was as follows

```py
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, no_of_sides):
        self.n = no_of_sides
        self.sides = [0 for i in range(no_of_sides)]
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self):
        Polygon.__init__(self,3)
```

It threw the same NameError when I ran this as the body of class Triangle

```
class Triangle(Polygon):
    self.a = 1
```

Comment: Self isn't in scope in the class body I expect.

Comment: It's unclear what you want exactly

Comment: Your traceback does not fit your code. The offending line does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do, is define a class attribute `a` in class `Triangle`. You don't need `self` to do that. `self` is used to access the object instance of a class.

If you would want to define `a` as an object attribute rather than a class attribute, you should do something like:

```
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self):
        Polygon.__init__(self, 3)
        self.a = 1
```

In this case, `a` is only defined upon class instantiation and accessible as `Triangle().a`, or as `self.a` inside other object-scope methods.

And if you want to define `a` as a class attribute, simply do:

```
class Triangle(Polygon):
    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

In this case, `a` is defined upon class definition and accessible even before instantiation, as `Triangle.a`